# Cannot read the decimal point in Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse, math, double, decimal

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double pi = 3.142;
        double T, v, a, x, r; 


        System.out.println("3.Centrifuge. The rotor of an ultracentrifuge rotates at x rev/s.");
        System.out.println("A particle at the top of the test tube is  r meter from the rotation axis.");
        System.out.println("Calculate it’s centripetal acceleration.");


        System.out.printf("Enter the number of rotation in rev/s : ");
        x = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("Enter the distance in meter : ");
        r = input.nextInt();

        T = 1/x;
        v = (2*pi*r)/T;
        a = (v*v)/r;

        System.out.println("\n\nAnswer");
        System.out.printf("The centripetal acceleration is : %.2f m/s^2\n", a);
    }

}
```

Hi all. This is my coding and it cannot run when I put decimal point. how to fix it?

Comment: Note that (despite the fact that you have to use `nextDouble()` instead of `nextInt()`), your default `Locale` may not support decimal point separator. You can specify one when you create your Scanner object. Ie : `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.UK);`

Answer (score 4):

Replace `input.nextInt();` with `input.nextDouble();`

```
x = input.nextInt(); // It will simply ignore decimal values
```

Hence you need to use `nextDouble()`

```
x = input.nextDouble(); // This will read the entire decimal value
```

Answer (score 1):

You read a int with

```
input.nextInt();
```

Try

```
input.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaScannerDouble {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String data = input.next();
    double decimalValue = Double.parseDouble(data);
    System.out.println("Decimal value : " + decimalValue);
    // test of decimal value
    double response = decimalValue / 0.1;

    System.out.println("response : " + response);
   }
}
```